# Bind regex match to variable in bash

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu

I've been trying to match a single IPv4 address out of an xml string and bind it to a variable for later use. I've tested the regex itself in some online testers and it appears to function with some sample outputs. I've also tested the BASH_REMATCH similar to the one below with a much simpler regex and pattern and it works. So is there a problem with my regex itself not compatible with bash?

Sample Script...

```
#!/bin/bash
rawxml="<ip-netmask>1.2.3.4/32</ip-netmask>"
ipv4regex="(((?:|\.)(2(?:5[0-5]|[0-4]\d)|1?\d?\d)){4})"

# Finding IP from $rawxml and binding it to its own variable
if [[ $rawxml =~ $ipv4regex ]]; then
        ipfound=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi

echo "IP found is "$ipfound""
```

Expected output here would be....

"IP Found is 1.2.3.4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
xmllint --xpath '//ip-netmask/text()' file.xml
```

A real XML parser is a better tool than regex to parse XML

Comment: Noted. Will give this a go.

Comment: Confirmed this was 1000x easier than trying to use regex. Updating OP with new method